# Having trouble building a vertical table in html using javascript once information is returned from the API

Tags: javascript, html

First I need to state that I am working on this for a course and I am limited to using a code editor (Atom), a bootstrap file structure that was provided for us, and my browser.

This is how my table currently displays (with headers on top and results underneath):

[This is how my table currently displays in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s42l.png)

This is how I am attempting to have my table displayed (with headers to the left and results to the right):
[This is how I want my table to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ032.png)

I tried giving a specific cell an id and then appending to that id, but it did not display as intended, so I'm sure where to go from here to fix that.

Below I have attached my html and js code as it is at current:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#get-weather-button').click(function(event) {

    $('#dynamicCityHeader').empty();
    $('#contentRows').empty();

    var weatherBaseURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=';

    var weatherQueryParams = '&appid=c43a8ae1bd246a40f99ed4afa60c8362&units=imperial';

    var zip = $('#enter-zip-code').val();

    var contentRows = $('#contentRows');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: weatherBaseURL + zip + weatherQueryParams,
      success: function(data) {

        var temp = data.main.temp;
        var humidity = data.main.humidity;
        var wind = data.wind.speed;
        var city = data.name;


        $('#dynamicCityHeader').append(' ' + city);


        var row = '<tr>';
        row += '<td>' + temp + ' F' + '</td>';
        row += '<td>' + humidity + '%' + '</td>';
        row += '<td>' + wind + '</td>';
        row += '</tr>';

        contentRows.append(row);

      },
      error: function() {
        $('#errorMessages')
          .append($('<li>')
            .attr({
              class: 'list-group-item list-group-item-danger'
            })
            .text('Error calling web service.  Please try again later.'));
      }
    });

  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Weather Rest CLient</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Weather Forecast Application</h1>
  <hr/>
  <ul class="list-group" id="errorMessages"></ul>
  <!--
        This will be a place to store error messages later
        -->
  <!--
        Add a row to our container 
        -->

  <!--This is the section for entering the ZIP code and the Get Weather button.-->
  <div id="enterZipCode">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="get-zipcode">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <label for="enter-zip-code" class="col-md-1 control-label">
                        ZIP code:
                    </label>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enter-zip-code" placeholder="ZIP code" required/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" id="get-weather-button" class="btn btn-default">
                            Get Weather
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <!--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Current Conditions for:
      <div id="dynamicCityHeader"></div>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table id="weatherTable" class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th width="40%">Temperature</th>
        <th width="30%">Humidity</th>
        <th width="15%">Wind Speed</th>
        <th width="15%"></th>
      </tr>
      <!--
             #3: This holds the returned weather data - we will add rows
            dynamically
             using jQuery
-->
      <tbody id="contentRows"></tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <!-- #5: Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/home.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of building a single row of `<td>`s and appending it, you need to build multiple `<tr>`s and append those.

Comment: Or do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2ctLhd0z/

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're creating a single row (`<tr>`) with multiple columns (`<td>`):

```
var row = '<tr>';
row += '<td>' + temp + ' F' + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + humidity + '%' + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + wind + '</td>';
row += '</tr>';
```

What you want is to create a row for each label/value pairing, like so:

```
var row = '<tr><td>Temperature:</td><td>' + temp + ' F</td></tr>';
row += '<tr><td>Humidity:</td><td>' + humidity + '% </td></tr>';
row += '<tr><td>Wind:</td><td>' + wind + '</td></tr>';
```

It's probably best to change the variable name to something other than `row` now that it contains multiple HTML rows, but I'll leave that to your discretion.

You'll also probably want to delete the (now inaccurate) table headers (`<th>`) below:

```
  <tr>
    <th width="40%">Temperature</th>
    <th width="30%">Humidity</th>
    <th width="15%">Wind Speed</th>
    <th width="15%"></th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: OK so even if I did something like this:  
            <table id="weatherTable" class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th width="40%">Temperature</th>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="30%">Humidity</th>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="15%">Wind Speed</th>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>

            <tbody id="contentRows"></tbody>
        </table>
I wouldnt be able to appened to a particular cell?

Comment: Sorry,just realized I made a typo. Will fix momentarily.